# How to correctly filter ruby enumerator

Tags: ruby

I have a array/enumarator of accounts. And all i want to do is filter by invoice_ref. So i basically want to split my array into multuple arrays with the same invoice_ref

Im still learning rails and i cant figure out the correct syntax on the select method. Most of the documentation deals with numbers and strings but i have an array of accounts

```
 accounts.each.select do |invoice_ref|
     invoice_ref == invoice_ref
 end
```

I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Possibly accounts.select{|account| account.invoice_ref == invoice_ref }

Answer (score 3):

We don't know how an account looks; it could be as simple as

```
p accounts.group_by( &:invoice_ref)
```

Comment: This is what the Account model instance contains

Comment: @LylePhillips It will give you a hash, that would contain invoice_refs as keys, and array of accounts as values. If you would like to get just arrays, grouped by invoice_refs - you can simply add `.values`. If you need to get all accounts by some particular invoice - it is better to do `accounts.select { |a| a.invoice_ref == invoice_to_search }`. Or you can query it directly from DataBase `accounts.where(invoice_ref: invoice_to_search)`.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are trying to group the array with the same values:

```
['1', '1', '2', '2'] to [['1', '1'], ['2', '2']]
```

Try the below:

```
 ['1', '1', '2', '2'].group_by(&:itself).values
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what an Account model looks like, this is just dummy data on dev

```
id: 21,
product_id: 108,
member_id: 20,
username: "5408",
realm: "infinity.co.za",
password: "9BtyPq3q",
comments: "",
contract_term: 1,
status: nil,
created_at: Mon, 11 May 2020 12:01:40 UTC +00:00,
updated_at: Wed, 20 May 2020 12:43:53 UTC +00:00,
invoiced: false,
invoice_ref: "4827132"
```

And when i do this

```
accounts.each.class => Enumarator
```

An I want to filter the Enumarator and group them by invoice_ref

Does that make sense ?